# How to convert candela into joule?

Tags: optics

How to convert candela into joule?

What equation can we use?

Is this site useful?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometry_%28optics%29

Comment: Did you read the main article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela? It gives you a rough idea about the conversion.

Comment: "J" here is the symbol for the dimension of luminous intensity, not the symbol for the unit joules.

Comment: "The candela is the luminous intensity, in a given direction, of a source that emits monochromatic radiation of frequency 540×1012 hertz and that has a radiant intensity in that direction of 1⁄683 watt per steradian.". Watt is Joule/s.

Comment: I agree there is no direct conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I ever use this unit, but according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela), the definition of 1 Candela is 1/683 Watts per steradian for a monochromatic source of frequency $540\times10^{12}$ Hz.

This webpage goes onto explain how the luminous intensity in Candelas depends on the spectrum of the source versus the sensitivity of the human eye.

So there is no straightforward conversion you have to use
$$  I(\lambda) =  \frac{I_v(\lambda)}{683.002\ V(\lambda)}\ ,$$
where $I(\lambda)$ is intensity in W/sr, $I_v(\lambda)$ is in Candelas and $V(\lambda)$ is the [mean sensitivity function of the human eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function). If there is a range of wavelengths present then this has to be integrated over that range.